# Finding earliest date in excel

Tags: excel

In one column I have to 10 times and dates (I have merged date and time in a cell). How do I find top 5 earliest dates and times? I can’t use function MIN() because I have date and time together. How should I write the function?

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Excel always stores date and time together, even if it's not displayed, so that should not matter.  (besides, if there are 6 records on the same day, wouldn't it be good to use the time to determine the earliest 5?)   There are plenty of examples online showing 5 to find the smallest *X* items of a list.  Please share **an example of your data** as well as anything you have tried so far. Also, see "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve]. More great tips from [so]'s top user [here](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to first format your data in date/time format in Excel.

Example, the following data is entered

```
16/7/2018 15:00
18/7/2018 12:05
25/8/2018 11:00
13/7/2018 09:00
15/7/2018 14:00
15/7/2018 11:00
```

You can use the formula =small(range, rank) to find the smallest n figure. For instance, =SMALL($A$1:$A$6,1) would give the smallest (earliest) date, 13/7/2018 09:00 in this case. =SMALL($A$1:$A$6, 2) would give the second smallest (earliest) date,  15/7/2018 11:00 in this case.

[image: Excel Earliest Date]